# Illegal instruction (core dumped) error: scanf in a while loop until EOF

Tags: c, error-handling, scanf, eof

So I wrote a function in C which gets input until `EOF`

```
while (scanf(" %c", &input) != EOF) {
     // do stuff
}
```

I tried to use the following test:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 
29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 
29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
10 20 30 40 50 _66_ 15 66bb
```

As an input to the program. It actually runs the program but at the end it finishes with the following error: `Illegal instruction (core dumped)`.

Other tests work fine, and after a quick check I found out that the problem begins after the last `50` (if I use only the numbers until `50` - it works fine). How to solve this problem?

Comment: The idiomatic loop is `while (scanf(" %c", &input) == 1)`

Comment: The `// do stuff` is probably where you run into trouble.  It's likely you have an array that you're writing to, but you write outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: For the general input case, testing that the result of `scanf()` is 1 is better than testing for EOF because the input might fail to convert to an integer, for example, and then `scanf()` would return 0, not EOF.  However, when reading a single character, you won't get a return value of 0 — so the code is safe, but it is not clear that you know that it is safe or why it is safe (if you did know, you probably wouldn't be asking this question).

Comment: I ran compiled your code with -Wall and -pedantic, and ran it with gdb.
I couldn't detect a problem with your inputs...

Comment: I supect there is a `%d` in there somewhere, as you are given, and talking about numbers. If so reading `_66_` will baulk (it's the one after the `50` you mention until which it works fine). If so, `scanf` won't return `EOF` but `0` and the input will remain stuck there.